# Trino string split > every character

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I want to do some profiling of characters that I seeing in a field, and a precursor of that is splitting a string value into its component characters.

With SQL Server I would have turned to the dark-side with a cursor, but I'm using AWS Athena so don't have that option.

Is there anyway I could approach this using Trino-SQL? I've taken a look at SPLIT and REGEXP_SPLIT(), but I can't see a way to pass them either
a) a blank value for the split parameter (to split on all chars)
b) to devise a regex pattern (to again split on all chars)
ex
Tried:

```
select s.str as original_str, u.str as exploded_value
from
(select 'www.google.com' as str) AS s
cross join unnest(regexp_split(s.str,'\D')) as u(str)
```

... which splits to 15 rows returned but no value for 'exploded value'. Is that because there is no distance between the splits?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `regexp_split(s.str,'\D')`? It's not doing what you think it's doing...

Comment: "but I can't see a way to pass them either a) a blank value for the split parameter"  Did you actually tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s.str as original_str, u.str as exploded_value
from
(select 'www.google.com' as str) AS s
cross join unnest(regexp_extract_all(s.str,'.')) as u(str)
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarassing - completely missed that function. Thanks for the pointer David!

Comment: FYI, regexp_split with empty string as separator also works, however it adds undesired empty strings for the string start and ending.